# How to convert base64 encoded string to file without disk I/O in Python (for HTTP requests)

Tags: python, python-requests

I want to send a file through requests library in Python, it accepts `file` type input. Here is a piece of working code I've tested myself.

```
FILES = []
f = open('/home/dummy.txt', 'rb')
# f : <type 'file'>
FILES.append(('file', f))
response = requests.post(url = 'https://dummy.com/dummy', headers = {'some_header':'content'}, data={'some_payload':'content'}, files=FILES)
```

This works just fine, now I have a base64 encoded string I just got from my database

```
base64_string = "Q3VyaW91cywgYXJlbid0IHlvdT8="
FILES = []
f = convert_base64_to_file(base64_string, "dummy.txt")
# f : <type 'file'>
FILES.append(('file', f))
response = requests.post(url = 'https://dummy.com/dummy', headers = {'some_header':'content'}, data={'some_payload':'content'}, files=FILES)
```

I need the `convert_base64_to_file` (which is an imaginary method). How do I achieve this without any disk I/O?

My `base64_string` doesn't have a filename. How do I simulate the filename so that it behaves just like I open a file from my disk?

I need the http request to post this:

```
------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="dummy.txt"
Content-Type: application/x-object

... contents of file goes here ...
```

That's why I need to specify the filename.

Comment: What is `convert_base64_to_file`?

Comment: @MegaIng it is an imaginary method that I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`io` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html):

```
import io
FILES = {}
f = io.BytesIO()
FILES{'file'] = ("dummy.txt", f)
response = requests.post(url = 'https://dummy.com/dummy', headers = {'some_header':'content'}, data={'some_payload':'content'}, files=FILES)
```

Here is the `convert_base64_to_file` function:

```
import base64
import io
def convert_base64_to_file(data):
    return io.BytesIO(base64.b64decode(data))
```

Comment: Where do I put the `base64_string`?

Comment: @William Better now?

Comment: @Megalng much better :), now there is a problem, there is no filename information in my `base64_string` so when I send it, it just says 'file', how do I simulate the filename as well?

Comment: @William look at the `FILES.append(('file', f))` what can you try changing to add a filename, that is not `'file'`?

Comment: @Megalng I know what you mean, I've update my question, basically I need to specify 2 inputs, name and filename for each `file`. Because I'm trying to communicate with an API that requires me to do that.

Comment: @Megalng I've already found a solution to the filename problem. Thanks a lot for your help, Have a good day!

Answer (score 0):

To complete Megalng answer which solves half of my problem, we can add a name to the constructed file by doing this:

```
import base64
import io
def convert_base64_to_file(base64_string,filename):
    f = io.BytesIO(base64.b64decode(base64_string))
    f.name = filename
    return f
```